# How do I teleport the player when they reach a specific Y-coordinate?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want the player to be teleported when they reach y=0. I tried the `/execute` command and it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Showing us some sort of effort will help us help you! What commands have you tried?

Comment: Reach from below or from above? Do you want to detect anything above or anything below 0? Do you want exactly 0.00000 or just roughly near 0?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you removed the bedrock from the world, there is no way to get to y=0. Commands like this:

```
/tp @p[y=0] 100 69 17
```

will rarely work because there are no block below y=0, and the player will fall past y=0 before they get teleported.

However, if there is a block underneath the player, then the `/tp` command should work, but not at y=0.